# get Google Assistant to always complete same action depending on the speaker?

Tags: automation, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, home-automation

I'm trying to play a prank on a roommate. We have a Google Nest Mini linked to my Google Assistant in the house, I would like it that anytime this particular person talks to the Google Nest, no matter what the command, it will always just play the song "Sweet Home Alabama", is this possible using Google's Dialogflow API?

I've gone through the documentation but haven't found anything on how to check who is actually speaking, or any way to create a blanket command that will do the same action for any command.

Answer (score 0):

While you can create routines that take a certain set of phrases and map them to custom behavior, there is no general way to override all behavior for a given user.